# append char[] to std::string with a spcific lenght

Tags: c++, string, serial-port

I want to receive a complete string from a serial port connection.
the receive function gives me a `char[]` and the value from the readed characters. So I want to add all readed chars to a `std::string` until the `\r\n` characters.
Here is my code the exception was at the append :

```
    //----- CHECK FOR ANY RX BYTES -----
    if (uart0_filestream != -1)
    {
        // Read up to 255 characters from the port if they are there
        unsigned char rx_buffer[256];
        int rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);      //Filestream, buffer to store in, number of bytes to read (max)
        if(rx_length > 0){
            std::string result = "";
        //  res = "";
            while (rx_length > 0)
            {
                result.append(*rx_buffer, 0, rx_length);
                rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);
            }
            std::cout << "rec" << result << std::endl;
        }

    }
```

has anybody an idea how to fix this ?

Comment: edit: im using the gcc compiler under debian

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
result.append(*rx_buffer, 0, rx_length);
```

to this

```
result.append(rx_buffer, 0, rx_length);
```

And make sure you have `#include <string>` in your CPP source file.

Comment: this gives me this exception : Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error (active)  no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::append [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list shit c:\Users\Marcel\Desktop\shit_new\shit\shit\main.cpp 445

Comment: @MarcelOchsendorf add `#include <string>` to the CPP file

Comment: this are my includes :#include <fcntl.h>   //Used for UART
#include <termios.h>  //Used for UART
#include <string.h>
#include "main_node_include.h" but its the same error

Comment: @MarcelOchsendorf you use C++, why do you include C headers? Also <string.h> doesn't have `append` method. Use `#include <string>` instead.